# How to use Custom Analytics in native iOS with MobileFirst?

Tags: objective-c, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

Where can I find a sample on how to use Custom Analytics using Objective-C in a native iOS app with IBM MobileFirst?

I want to be able to create custom value analytics charts in the MobileFirst analytics console.

I tried different coding versions to do that, but it does not work

```
NSDictionary *stringInventory = @{
                                  @"GERMANY" : @"1",
                                  @"USA" : @"2",
                                  @"GREECE" : @"3",
                                  @"UK" : @"4",
                                  };
NSDictionary *inventory = @{
                            @"GERMANY" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                            @"USA" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                            @"GREECE" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                            @"UK" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                            };
// OPTION 1
// *******
OCLogger *logger = [OCLogger getInstanceWithPackage:@"CalculatorViewController"];  // IBM MF LOGGER
[OCLogger setCapture:TRUE]; // IBM MF LOGGER 
[OCLogger setAutoSendLogs:TRUE]; // IBM MF LOGGER
[logger log:@"success - online"]; // IBM MF LOGGER
[logger log:@"Using OCLogger for WL Analytis"]; // IBM MF LOGGER  
[logger logWithLevel:OCLogger_ANALYTICS message:@"This is a Analyitics Message CalculatorViewController:onSuccess" args:@"USA" userInfo:inventory];  // IBM MF LOGGER
[logger logWithLevel:OCLogger_ANALYTICS message:@"This is a Analyitics Message CalculatorViewController:onSuccess" args:@"GERMANY" userInfo:stringInventory];  // IBM MF LOGGER

// Option 2
// ********
WLAnalytics *doAnaylitics = [WLAnalytics sharedInstance]; // IBM MF ANALYTICS
[doAnaylitics enable]; // IBM MF ANALYTICS
[doAnaylitics log:@"MY ANALYITIS LOG" withMetadata:inventory[@"GERMANY"]]; // IBM MF ANALYTICS
[doAnaylitics send]; // IBM MF ANALYTICS
//[doAnaylitics setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:stringInventory]; // IBM MF Analytics
[doAnaylitics log:@"MY ANALYITIS LOG" withMetadata:stringInventory[@"USA"]];
[doAnaylitics send];    // IBM MF ANALYTICS
[doAnaylitics disable]; // IBM MF ANALYTICS
```

I found [this getting started](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/moving-production/operational-analytics/) but there is no sample for Objective-C.

Comment: This? https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/advanced-client-side-development/remote-controlled-client-side-log-collection/logging-native-ios-objective-c/

Comment: Idan@ Thanks for the fast feedback: 

But is does not really help, because the OCLogger basically works for "non custom analytics" topics. At the end I want to be able to create custom charts in MF Analytics Console.

I ment maybe the operation   [logger logWithLevel:<#(OCLogType)#> message:<#(NSString *)#> args:<#(va_list)#> userInfo:<#(NSDictionary *)#>] would help. Using the "OCLogger_ANALYTICS" as type, but that didn't work. So I tried to use the WLAnalytics class but didn't not work.

I do something wrong ... but what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue that you are coming across is the log data that you are trying to send. With the NSDictionary you want it to be a key value pair, right now you are only trying to send a value. You can have as many key value pairs as you want but one is the simplest.

```
NSDictionary *inventory = @{
    @"GERMANY" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
};
```

Using this NSDictionary my property for custom charts is going to be Germany and my term will be the number 1.

To send this NSDictionary using WLAnalytics API you would make these API calls.

```
[[WLAnalytics sharedInstance] log:@"Hello" withMetadata:inventory];
[[WLAnalytics sharedInstance] send];
```

Comment: hmm ... today I was able to verify the answer and I didn't work :-(.
I can not find the property "AUSTRIA" in the custom chart selection.

I used:
    NSDictionary *inventoryAUSTRIA = @{
                                  @"AUSTRIA" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                                  };   
    [[WLAnalytics sharedInstance] log:@"Hello Message AUSTRIA 1" withMetadata:inventoryAUSTRIA];

    [[WLAnalytics sharedInstance] send];

Comment: With a other MF Remote Server it worked ... it seems I have problem with other server.